# Add social network link with icons in telegram bot message template.html

Tags: telegram, telegram-webhook

I'm using a telegram bot with html template. Send messages and photo by Python **requests** library
I'm trying to add links social networks to below the message [image: social links]

I saw examples but couldn't do the same in the telegram bot template.html.
Documentation about html style [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style). But still couldn't understand how can I do it.